# Why are boost::scoped_ptr or std::unique_ptr non-copyable?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, scoped-ptr

In [boost::scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm), says "It supplies a basic "resource acquisition is initialization" facility, without shared-ownership or transfer-of-ownership semantics."
It is done through some non-copyable mechanism.

My question is why is there requirement for no shared-ownership?

Here is what I mean:

```
 template <typename T>
 class my_scoped_ptr
 {
 public:
  // constructor  implemented not shown here
  // operator*() implemented not shown here
  // operator -> implemented not shown here
  ~my_scoped_ptr()
  {
   delete my_p;
   my_p = NULL;
  }
 private:
  T * my_p;
 };


 void foo()
 {
  my_scoped_ptr<someclass> p (new someclass());
  my_scoped_ptr<someclass> q (p); // both p & q point to same my_p object
  // may be an exception is raised
 }
```

Ok now , regardless whether or not exception is raised the my_p will be deleted. 
so, when the code get out of foo's scope ...my_scope_ptr p destructor is called, deleting my_p and setting my_p to null. 
Now my_scope_ptr q destructor is called again deleting my_p , which is null at this point. 
 It seems at destruction time I could care less whether a remaining copied pointer is pointing to a valid object.

So, why would I need to care that my_scoped_ptr should not be copyable? I don't see any harm of  a ptr being copyable, if the ptr takes care of deleting the object pointed to , once it exits the scope. ??!!

Comment: "which is null at this point" How did its member variable get updated?  That's your answer. It's possible (see `shared_ptr`), but at a non-zero cost. And that's why there's at least two smart pointer types: one for simple no-overhead, and one for shared with-overhead.

Comment: `p.my_p` and `q.my_p` are two different variables, so setting one of them to NULL will not change the other.

Comment: hmm; @GManNickG @green lantern I am bit confused here.  What happens if I only do `delete my_p` and DO NOT set `my_p=NULL`.So, since I did not specify a copy/assignment constructor, compiler will provide miranda copy , which will do a shallow copy. After which both `p.my_p` and `q.my_p` points to the same bits of info. Now if I do `delete p.my_p` I am effectively deleting what my_p points to. so `q.my_p` is left dangling I agree to that. But its left dangling at the point when my function is going out of scope. Why not implement this solution..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void foo()
 {
  my_scoped_ptr<someclass> p (new someclass());
  my_scoped_ptr<someclass> q (p); // both p & q point to same my_p object
  // may be an exception is raised
 }
```

As the function ends (return or throw) and `q` goes out of scope, the destructor for `q` will `delete` the `someclass` object.  Then immediately afterward, `p` goes out of scope and its destructor will `delete` the `someclass` object again.

It is not valid to `delete` the same pointer twice! (unless `new` happened to return it again in the meantime).

[ And if any C++ implementation tried to make it valid, it would either have to link together all raw pointers with the same value (which is what `shared_ptr` is for), or else keep track of what addresses have been deleted, which means they're still using memory of some sort and not really freed up. ]